# How can I reuse my infix-to-postfix operator for \psVolume?

Tags: pstricks

### Constraints

Assume I don't want to use `infix-RPN` package for unknown logical reason (seriously). Instead I want to use my own `A2P` describe as follows. In the first case it succeeds but it fails for the second case.

### Case 1 (succeed)

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\pstVerb{/A2P {exec AlgParser cvx /t ED  exec AlgParser cvx exec t RadtoDeg PtoC} def }

\def\RR#1{(2^(#1/10))}
\def\TT#1{(#1)}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-3,-3)(3,3)
  \psplot[algebraic,polarplot]{2 Pi mul neg}{4 Pi mul}{\RR{x}}
  \pscircle*[linecolor=red  ](!\RR{7*Pi/2} \TT{7*Pi/2} A2P){2pt}
  \pscircle*[linecolor=green](!{(2^(t/10))} {(3*Pi/2)} A2P){2pt}
  \pscircle*[linecolor=blue ](!\RR{t} \TT{5*Pi/2} A2P){2pt}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

### Case 2 (failed)

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-func}

\pstVerb{/A2P {exec AlgParser cvx /t ED  exec AlgParser cvx exec t RadtoDeg PtoC} def }
\def\f(#1){(sin(#1)+1.2)}%

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-0.5,-3)(7,3)
    \psVolume[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=orange!50,linecolor=blue](0,\psPiTwo){10}{{\f(x)} A2P}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

### Question

How can I reuse

```
\pstVerb{/A2P {exec AlgParser cvx /t ED  exec AlgParser cvx exec t RadtoDeg PtoC} def }
```

for `\psVolume`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your first case you apply `A2P` to the x and y values. The function parameter for `\psVolume`, however, evaluates to a single value only:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-func}

\pstVerb{/A2P {exec AlgParser cvx exec} def }
\def\f(#1){(sin(#1)+1.2)}%

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-0.5,-3)(7,3)
    \psVolume[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=orange!50,linecolor=blue](0,\psPiTwo){10}{{\f(x)} A2P}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]